# Deepcopy in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any deepcopy in tensorflow? Consider the following operation:

```
tt = tf.get_variable('t',shape=[2,2])
tt1= tf.identity(tt[0].assign([1,1]))
tt2 = tf.identity(tt[1].assign([2,2]))
```

I want tt1 to only edit the first row of tt, and tt2 only edits the second row. This is what I get now:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(tt1))
    print(sess.run(tt2))
```

which outputs:

```
 [[ 1.          1.        ]
  [-1.15554953 -0.78545022]]

 [[ 1.  1.]
  [ 2.  2.]].
```

Instead, I want something like:

```
 [[ 1.          1.        ]
  [-1.15554953 -0.78545022]]

 [[ -0.31531231 1.6651651]
  [ 2.  2.]].
```

As you see, the second variable is also affected by the first assign. Is there a way to have independent copies, without copying the references to tensors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your deepcopy in tensorflow as follows:

```
tt = tf.get_variable('t',shape=[2,2])
deepcopy = tf.Variable(tt.initialized_value())    
tt1= tf.identity(tt[0].assign([1,1]))
tt2 = tf.identity(deepcopy[1].assign([2,2]))
```

This will give you the desired output:

```
[[ 1.          1.        ]
 [-1.01704359 -1.16236985]]
[[-0.44483608  1.1660043 ]
 [ 2.          2.        ]]
```